# Not able to install my python package with setup.py anymore

Tags: python, package, egg

I wrote a python package and I install it with `python setup.py install` like 3-4 months ago. Everything was working fine so far, I was editing the files and everything worked fine. However, today I tried to install it again in another machine and I get the following error when I try to import:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lb-0.1-py2.7.egg/lb/res/config.cfg'
```

It complains about a configuration file that is inside the res directory. In that directory I did not have the `__init__.py` file. I added and the error is still appearing.

What is going on ?

**EDIT:**

I found the solution: I did not have this problem previously because I installed my packet with pip install -e "." that links the package to the place where the actual code is. So the /res directory that has no python files was found. To solve that without using the pip command above you have to add in the root of the package a file called MANIFEST.in and inside the file the line : recursive-include lb/res *

Comment: I found the solution:

I did not have this problem previously because I installed my packet with `pip install -e "."` that links the package to the place where the actual code is. So the /res directory that has no python files was found.

To solve that without using the `pip` command above you have to add in the root of the package a file called `MANIFEST.in` and inside the file the line :

recursive-include lb/res *

Comment: Please post your solution as a answer to your question. Don't put it in the comments.